# Query string in route.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, routes

I would like to add another explicit query parameter to my route.

Right now, i have this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :format => true, :constraints => {:format => :json} do
    get     'proxies/random(?type=:proxy_type)'   => 'proxies#random'
```

What i want to do is add one more `(?origin=:origin)` query param.
I just can't find any documentation or examples on this.

I belive i should have something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :format => true, :constraints => {:format => :json} do
    get     'proxies/random(?type=:proxy_type&origin=:origin)'   => 'proxies#random'
```

or maybe this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :format => true, :constraints => {:format => :json} do
    get     'proxies/random(?type=:proxy_type)(?origin=:origin)'   => 'proxies#random'
```

Whats the right way to do this?

*Btw, here's what i'm doing in my controller:*

```
  [...] 
  before_filter :find_randomly, only: :random
  [...]

  def find_randomly
    if params[:origin].nil? or params[:origin].blank?
      relation = ProxiesCatalogueProxy.where(blacklisted: false)
    else
      relation = ProxiesCatalogueProxy.where(blacklisted: false, origin: params[:origin])
    end

    @proxy = if params[:type].nil? or params[:type].blank?
              relation.order("RAND()").first
            else
              relation.where(proxy_type: params[:type]).order("RAND()").first
            end

  end
```

Also, can someone provide any good resource/material on this topic?
Thx.

Comment: for query strings, you don't need to write route definitions.. Whatever you will pass will be [available in the `params`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string). You can use [`permit`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) method to blacklist unwanted query string params ofcourse.

Comment: It sort of looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @ArupRakshit supose i don't add an explicit declaration for type and origin...
If i just hit the route 'proxies/random' (no parameters) wont that raise some kind of exception?

Cuz, in the controller i already have statements like:
   "if params[:origin].nil? or params[:origin].blank?"
and
   "if params[:type].nil? or params[:type].blank?"
that are expecting origin and type params.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hardcode parameters into your routes you can do something like:

`get 'proxies/random(?type=:proxy_type)' => 'proxies#random', origin: 'some value'`

This won't affect URL matching and will add origin into your params hash accessible in the corresponding controller and action as `params[:origin]`.

Comment: nice! tks! that's ALMOST it!

i want a default value that can be overwritten, so if i get a route that explicit contains the origin param, e.g "/proxies/random.json?origin=other", i want to get the "other" value for the orgin param, not the default value.

Comment: Oh ok then you don't want to use routes for that.  The best way to do what you want is to add a "before_action" method in your ApplicationController that will be called every request. That action should check params[:origin].blank? and redirect accordingly.